# Firebase receive documentID when adding and updating documents to firebase with flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am adding a new document to my firestore group 1, and use the new documentID of that group to update two other documents. Afterwards, I'd like to save the documentID from group 1 in a variable in order to pass it to my widgets.

How can I receive and save the documentID when adding a new document to group 1 without causing an extra firestore read? I don't understand why the code below works except for

```
valueId = value.documentID
```

Thanks

```
onPressed: () {
                firestore.collection('Gruppe').add({
                  'Group': messageTextController.text.trim(),
                  'Gruppenersteller': loggedInUser.uid,
                  'Gruppenmitglieder': FieldValue.arrayUnion([
                    loggedInUser.email,
                    widget.userEmail,
                  ]),
                  'Angelegt': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                }).then((value) => {
                      firestore
                          .collection('Nutzer')
                          .document(loggedInUser.uid)
                          .updateData({
                        'Slates': FieldValue.arrayUnion([value.documentID])
                      }),
                      firestore
                          .collection('Nutzer')
                          .document(widget.userNutzerId)
                          .updateData({
                        'Slates': FieldValue.arrayUnion([value.documentID])
                      }),
                      valueId = value.documentID,
                    });
                print('valueID');
                print(valueId);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the random ID of a document before it's added like this:

```
val docRef = firestore.collection('Gruppe').doc()
val docId = docRef.documentID;
```

Then you can go on and create the document with `set()`:

```
docRef.set(...)
```

---

In your code above, I would expect that `print(valueId)` to **not** print the assigned value of `value.documentID`, because `add()` and `then()` are asynchronous and return immediately with a Future.  In fact, any function that returns a Future will do so immediately.  The callback you provide to `then()` will be invoked some time later, after the operation is complete.  So, effectively, your code is trying to print the document ID **before** it's been assigned.  That's why I'm suggesting that you get it immediately of the reference instead of trying to get it later.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But getting the documentID before it's added would mean I pay for an extra read/ write?

Comment: No.  The client app generates the ID randomly before anything ever happens on the backend.